# PHP - шаблонизатор Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Не могу получить доступ к глобальной переменной `$smarty`, в которой все данные.
Версия `3.0.7`и обработка PHP кода везде включена.

Comment: Дабавте фрагмент кода, где у вас возникли затруднения.

Comment: глобальной переменной `$smarty` не существует, вы должны самостоятельно создать экземпляр, как например это продемонстрировано в [описании метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/smarty/info)